# How should I solve "no such directory" error at CDPATH with environmental variable on Windows 10 Emacs?

Tags: init-file, microsoft-windows, environment

I have installed GNU Emacs on Windows 10. When I open it, I get an error.

```
Warning (initialization): An error occured while loading
'c:/Users/[redacted]/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/init.el':

error: No such directory found at CDPATH environment variable.
```

Adding CDPATH as an environmental variable doesn't seem to change it. What should I do? Was it looking for a directory, instead of my init.el file?

Comment: You should start Emacs with `--debug-init` to get a backtrace.

Comment: May be a noob question; but how do I do that in windows?

Comment: Open a `cmd` box, and enter `C:/path/to/Emacs/bin/emacs.exe --debug-init`

Comment: Thanks for your help, the output is [this](https://i.imgur.com/RsJxBF3.png).

Just a note that `~/Documents/workshop` is the directory for a git repo with org-mode files that I usually work on- on a mac and linux. Could it be an error with how windows interprets the "~"?

Comment: Thanks for your help @npostavs. I've solved it (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

How the issue started:

1. To make work faster/easier on my Linux and Mac computers, I added a line to my emacs init file:

> (cd "~/Documents/workshop/")

2. I then committed to my emacs repository on Github.
3. By the time I set up Windows, I forgot about this. So I installed Emacs and cloned into the relevant repo. Down comes my init file.
4. I set up the relevant directories, but decide that any repositories should be separated into a "Github" directory, because playing video games spams your Documents with hundreds of save directories.
5. Upon doing that, I start Emacs. Emacs obviously complains because I don't have the directory.

May seem like a rookie error, but I posted it just in case anyone else does something similar.